# Is it possible to redirect to an Azure AD tenant specific login page before username is entered?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are developing a MVC multi tenant application that use Azure AD and OpenIdConnect for authentication. Users that do not have their own Azure AD tenant will get a user in our tenant domain. Signup and authentication works fine and we have also customized the login page for our tenant (i.e. company logo). 
The problem is with the "landing page" for authentication. Today, all users are redirected to a page at login.microsoftonline.com similar to this one:

[image]

I want all users to land on my domain tenant customized login page (also at login.microsoftonline.com), so that they see our logo:

[image]

If a user from another tenant (not my domain tenant) enters their e-mail, they are redirected to their company login page. That is excellent. The same happens in the generic landing page for my domain tenants and any other tenants. Which is also excellent. So, how can I get all users to land on our customized login page? Btw, all users are redirected from applications that we control, so we have full controll of the code that sends the users to Azure AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by simply appending a `whr` query string parameter. Its value must match a verified domain which has status `active` under the `domains` section in your Azure Active Directory (Azure Managment Portal):

[image]

For example, if your domain is `tradesolution.no` (and it is the `active` domain in your AAD), you have to redirect users to:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/?whr=tradesolution.no

Append the `whr` parameter before or after any other parameters required by the OpenID Connect flow. Check out [this article too](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/03/18/custom-branding-extended-to-all-sign-in-scenarios.aspx).

Comment: for OIDC you can use the parameter `domain_hint` as well.

Comment: Thanks, this but me on the right path :) I ended up adding domain hint in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications->RedirectToIdentityProvider and that worked! 
RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>                       {           
  context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "<activeDomain>";
  return Task.FromResult(0);
 },

Answer (score -2):

We blogged about how to achieve this scenario with Open ID Connect, SAML-P and WS-Fed. See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/02/11/how-to-use-azure-ad-to-land-users-on-their-custom-login-page-from-within-your-app.aspx)
Note that you need to be able to inject the query string parameter into the sign-in URL.

Comment: Add releveant information here as later external links can break

Comment: ...aaaand the external link broke.